# How to install wxWidgets with Code::Blocks?

Tags: codeblocks, wxwidgets

I'm a windows developer and I need to use Code::Blocks
to develope multiplataform C++ GUI applications.

After installing Code::Blocks and wxWidgets in my first try to do a simple "Hello World" application, the IDE show me a box with **$(#wx)**

What is the **$(#wx)** ?

Googling for tutorials I see this
[image]

What is the **-g** ?

Finally the following error message appear:

[image: error message]

For 3 days I'm trying over and over again without success !
I even try **wxPack**. Nothing works !

With VC++, C++Builder and even wxDev-C++ this is straightforward
Only Code::Blocks is so difficult !

Googling, I find many people with the same error, but the advices they get didn't work for me !

Can someone tell me step by step what I must do?

Thank you.

Comment: how did you build wxWidgets? The error message you posted suggests that you need to use Debug build of the library, since you have "-g" option set.

Comment: @Igor,  I didn't. I download wxWidgets and ran the setup program to a directory. Because this didn't work, i install wxPack (because the tutorials said that wxPack has the binaries, or, saying in another way, they are precompiled).

Comment: I don't know anything about wxPack. But since you downloaded wxWidgets and ran setup... I presume you have gcc/MinGW installed on the machine as ou are using C::B, right. Then go to the wxWidgets/build/msw directory and run: mingw32 -f makefile.gcc BUILD=Debug and then try to build you project. Adjust accordingly for the MinGW executable name.

Comment: it just not possible to provide the binaries for every single compiler/version there is. So you should compile the library first. Setup only unpack the source code of the library in the directory of you choice. Then you build it and only then you can build and run you project.

Comment: however, it is weird that the company requesting the C::B only and not MSVC. It is native Windows compiler/IDE and presumably will produce better binaries. Also, I suggest you start from scratch, getting rid of wxPack and re-downloading wxWidgets.

Comment: One whole week lost catching errors after errors. Code::Blocks is undoubtly the WORST IDE I ever saw. The Fortran edition doesn't even compile Fortran sources even tought the IDE shows 3 Fortran compilers! All bugy. The wxWidget projects are a joke. I can't run ONE JUST SINGLE project. Code::Blocks MUST have wxWidgets bundled with the compiler, as wxDev-C++ has.Install Code::Blocks and have to compile wxWidgets is like selling a car and saying to the buyer: Now you must build the wheels.

Answer (score 2):

Your frustration comes, as usually does, from your ignorance. If your are required to learn about C::B, well, that's life. Don't waste time on getting so angry, life is short.

CodeBlocks are not tied to a compiler. You can use VC++, MinGW, TDM-GCC, GCC, etc. Thus, you must tell C::B the compiler to use. You may use different compilers for different "targets" (see below).

C::B is not tied to any library either. If you want to use wxWidgets you must tell C::B about the needed files and where to find them.

It's very common that people who use C::B use MinGW as the compiler. That's why when you first install C::B it searches for MinGW and, if found, set it as the default compiler. You can set your own preference in `Settings->Compiler`. Same goes for the debugger, usually GDB.

As a side note, be aware that MinGW is ONLY 32 bits. There's a different compiler (MinGW 64). TDM-GCC offers both compilers (and their GDB versions) at once, I recommend installing 32/64 versions in different folders and setting them in C::B as different compilers. For Linux, the "mother" GCC is the de-facto standard.

When you build your app you must define a `target`. This is nothing else but a way of telling things like "I want a 32 bit library" or "I want a 64 executable". In your **required** *project* you may set several targets. Select the desired one before compiling (combobox in the main tool bar).

While developing it's very advisable to set a target as a "debug". This means you want to use the debugger. This requires to use "debug symbols". With GCC (or one of its "children", MinGW...) you acomplish it but adding `-g` as a flag to the compiler.

Now you understand that probably you set not only one, but several targets like "release 64 exe", "debug 32 exe" etc. Right?

**wxWidgets joins in scene**

Despite C::B is made with wxWidgets, it doesn't ship with it. Download the version you like from [wxWidgets site](https://www.wxwidgets.org/). While some binaries are offered, if you use some other compiler or some other parameters then you need to compile wxWidgets on your own. See the `docs/msw/install.txt` and learn about the different configurations (release, debug, static/dynamic lib, etc). Your "target" must match the wxWidgets configuration, so better build several versions, same as your targets. And don't forget to use the same parameters for your app target as you used to each wxWidgets target. You can do this at `Project->Build options`.

As with any compiler you must tell where to find the libraries and the headers. And the libraries you want to use. The Windows libraries (kernel32, user32, etc, they are a lot, ask in another thread) and the wxWidgets libraries.

When you update your app perhaps you use a newer wxWidgets version, but also want to support an older version with other wxWidgets version. You have several folders. For your project you should update all directories. Can this be done shortly? Yes. in C::B you can define `variables`(e.g. $wx31dir) and use them like `$(wx31dir)/include`. Redefining the var saves you a lot of typing.

You can use a *global* var `$(#wx31dir)` or several, project fitted vars. Your decision.

Finally, C::B offers a project template for a wxWidgets app. It will ask you some locations (wx dirs) and vars. If you don't understand well what it does, better don't use it and set everything on your own. First time is hard, I know. Go ahead and you'll get it if you pay attention to needed steps.

Have you read the [CodeBlocks manual](http://www.codeblocks.org/user-manual)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I stiil think that Code::Blocks SHOULD be bundled with wxWidgets, because other IDEs do that. Look at Lazarus. I have Lazarus for almost any platform and the windows version that I download have the LCL framework bundled. Its only install & run, out of the box.

Comment: I have another question: I give Code::Blocks a try and this time I tried to compile wxWidgets. As you can expected I get LOTS of errors. Can I post the errors here or I need to post in another thread ?

Comment: Compiling wxWidgets has nothing to do with C::B. Better a new thread with the command you used to compile wx and some errors. Please, search first for a similar question with same errors.

Answer (score 1):

Since you having hard time using C::B, I suggest you switch to CodeLite which I find simpler to start with than C::B (My experience). Everything you need is documented on [CodeLite Wiki](https://wiki.codelite.org/pmwiki.php/Developers/BuildingWxWidgetsWin). Creating project is well documented with screenshots but before you compile, open environment variables (`Settings->Environment Variables`) and add line `WXWIN=/path/to/your/wxwidgets/installation` and compile as it is explained there.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch....
You do not need to interact with code::blocks at all to use wxwidgets.
You can simple download wx header and binary package (depends of your compiler), place it on directory and import (with #include) it in your source code.
I do not see what is relevant to C::B? You can use any library without compiling and setting any variable in your editor (IDE) - but then you lack of lot of feuters.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that 
 [Using wxWidgets Pre Built Binary in CodeBlocks at wxWidgets wiki](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Using_wxWidgets_Pre-Built_Binary_in_CodeBlocks) 
and 
[Using wxWidgets (MSW) 3.0 Binary with Code::Blocks Scripted Wizard](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Using_wxWidgets_(MSW)_3.0_Binary_with_Code::Blocks_Scripted_Wizard#Running_the_CB_Wizard)
would be best and useful answer for your question.

Even I want to use wheel for my convenience every day, but I don't want to invent the wheel every day again and again.
Even that your question is about wxWidgets and Code::Blocks for MS Windows, and that the answer links are of the wxWidgets and Code::Blocks own, 
 [For recommended stability, I include the full screenshot of this document of wxWidgets own wiki](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynpge.png) 
and 
 [this of Code::Blocks own wiki](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAidm.png)